# what is the maximum number of vxworks windmarks that can be created?

Tags: javascript, vxworks

I have a vxworks 6.9 embedded web talking to a FireFox browser running JavaScript,
and after adding some more windmarks, each one now gets this error displayed on the page:

WindMark(aaa_windmark) read attempt failed. errno: ffffff9a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of vxworks windmarks is limited only by available memory.

The error above "errno: fffffff9a" went away after restarting the Windows computer, and completely rebuilding the VxWorks project.

Comment: Sounds like a classic memory leak.